# Wrap link around an element in twig

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I have a twig template for a custom block, I want the entire block to be wrapped in a link. I'm using the link field, but I'm not sure how to get the url from the field within the twig template. This seems like it should work, but doesn't:

```
{{ content.field_link.0.getUri() }}
```

I've looked at `url()` and `path()`, but they are dealing with routing, so I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Note, I would like to use either external or internal links in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I was missing the `['#url']` part of the array. In order to get the url from the link field I called:

```
{{ content.field_link.0['#url'].getUri() }}
```

I do miss the ability to copy-paste from `dpm()`.

Comment: If you miss dpm() and you haven't found devel's kint submodule, you should look into it.

Comment: I use kint, but it doesn't give me an easily copiable string to "dig down" to variable